# Can CloudMagic search the contents of a file in Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, evernote

It seems like CloudMagic can only search the contents of a note in Evernote, but not in Dropbox. Only file names are searchable in Dropbox. Is it possible to search the contents of a file located in Dropbox using this feature?